How to multi viewport in godot 4?
I have a question regarding the screen of godot 4.(c# ver)
I want to place the dungeon map part (ex, 500x500 size) in the middle of the top, move the character map on that screen, and separate the remaining parts (UI or Etc part) into other screens.
enter image description here
What I tried was subviewport, but it doesn't work.
I would like to know how to configure the node and its overall aspects.(at godot editor)
How to multi viewport in godot 4

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
